# « Boîte à épices » ou « Boîte aux épices » ?

Tags: articles, pluriel, mots-composés, à

J'ai récemment aperçu dans une boutique une « boîte à épices ». Les boutiques en ligne proposent aussi bien d'acheter des « boîtes à épices » que des « boîtes aux épices ». Laquelle de ces deux expressions doit-on donc utiliser ?

> - Boîte **à** épices
> - Boîte **aux** épices

J'ai tenté de trouver des expressions similaires ([Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bo%C3%AEte+aux+*%2Cbo%C3%AEte+%C3%A0+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cbo%C3%AEte%20aux%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20aux%20lettres%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20aux%20saintes%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20aux%20ordures%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20aux%20poudres%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20aux%20id%C3%A9es%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20aux%20souvenirs%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20aux%20questions%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20aux%20Lombards%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20aux%20parois%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20aux%20m%C3%A9dicaments%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cbo%C3%AEte%20%C3%A0%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20%C3%A0%20fum%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20%C3%A0%20feu%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20%C3%A0%20musique%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20%C3%A0%20vapeur%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20%C3%A0%20outils%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20%C3%A0%20cuir%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20%C3%A0%20tiroir%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20%C3%A0%20graisse%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20%C3%A0%20couleurs%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bbo%C3%AEte%20%C3%A0%20%C3%A9toupes%3B%2Cc0#) en liste quelques autres), et les deux usages semblent coexister :

> - Boîte **aux** lettres
> - Boîte **à** chaussures
> - Pot **à** crayons
> - Boîte **à** idées
> - Boîte **à** outils

D'après mon intuition, « boîte à épices » devrait désigner une boîte destinée à contenir des épices, tandis que « boîte aux épices » désignerait une hypothétique boîte comestible assaisonnée avec lesdites épices, similaire à un « gâteau aux épices ».

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bo%C3%AEte+%C3%A0+%C3%A9pices%2Cbo%C3%AEte+aux+%C3%A9pices&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbo%C3%AEte%20%C3%A0%20%C3%A9pices%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbo%C3%AEte%20aux%20%C3%A9pices%3B%2Cc0) semble indiquer une préférence pour « boîte à épices ».

Toute référence à l'[Épice gériatrique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89pice_g%C3%A9riatrique) vous rapporte évidemment un point bonus imaginaire !

Comment: A noter qu'on peut également dire "Boîte à lettres", qui pose la même question...

Comment: @Random En effet, « boîte à lettres » semble [nettement moins courant](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bo%C3%AEte+aux+lettres%2Cbo%C3%AEte+%C3%A0+lettres&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbo%C3%AEte%20aux%20lettres%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbo%C3%AEte%20%C3%A0%20lettres%3B%2Cc0), mais existe néanmoins (je l'ignorais).

Comment: @Random Moi francophone de France je dépose le courrier que j'ai écrit dans la **boîte aux lettres** que les services postaux videront pour en acheminer  le contenu aux différents destinataires et le facteur dépose dans la **boîte à lettres** de mon immeuble le courrier que  le service postal a acheminé jusqu'à mon domicile. Je sais que la majorité des gens ne fait pas la distinction. Le *dictionnaire culturel en langue française* donne « boîte à lettres » comme synonyme de « boîte aux lettres », ça confirmerait la remarque comme quoi « boîte à lettres » est moins courant.

Comment: @Laure Parlant nativement la même langue dans le même pays, j'irai dans votre sens : les *boites aux lettres* reçoivent les lettres de tous les émetteurs de courrier pour tous les destinataires, tandis que ma *boite à lettres*, dont je suis le seul destinataire, les reçoit -- Je plussoierais ce commentaire s'il se transforme en réponse :) .

Comment: Personnellement, je n'avait jamais entendu parlé de distinction entre les deux, je dirais naturellement que je vais chercher mon courrier dans ma boîte aux lettres. Mais n'ayant aucune certitude à ce sujet, je serais tenté de dire que je me trompe... :)

Comment: @Random c'est drôle, je dis exactement l'inverse ^^ je dépose mon courrier dans la boîte à lettres et vais le chercher dans ma boîte aux lettres... Mais qui a raison ? :0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Boîte à*, or more generally any container + à, means "a container whose purpose is to contain..."

> *Placard à balais*
>
> *Moule à gâteaux*
>
> *Plat à tarte*
>
> *Boîte à épingles*

When used in that sense, it doesn't matter what the box actually contains. You can say *J'ai mis le thé dans la boîte à épices*, for example.

*Boîte aux lettres* is an idiomatic term used specifically for a box that's used to hold things for some kind of mail delivery. You can have a *boîte à lettres* anywhere as long as it's a container in which you intend to put letters. But the *boîte aux lettres* is a container that someone will either deliver letters into, or pick up letters from. It can also be used in figurative contexts, eg for email (*ma boîte aux lettres sur yahoo*) whereas you wouldn't hear that usage for *boîte à lettres*.

Finally you can use "à" in its normal sense, with a box as with anything else, to refer to the attributes of the box, in phrases like *la boîte au couvercle cassé* (the box with a broken lid).

In that last sense, you could use *la boîte aux épices* to talk about the box that currently contains the spices, and people would understand it that way. But it would not be the common way to describe such a box; likely people would say something else like *la boîte d'épices*, *la boîte où sont les épices*, *la boîte avec les épices*.

Comment: *Boîte à lettres* is often used interchangeably with *boîte aux lettres*. While *aux* is more common, *à* is also idiomatic, and many people switch between them without a second thought.

Comment: Interesting. I have personally never used or heard *boîte à lettres* in that context, but see that it's listed here as a "néologisme". Maybe this is becoming more common of late? http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0

Answer (score 4):

Rappellons-nous tout d'abord que "aux" est une contraction de "à les". On hésite donc entre (1) "boîte à épices" et (2) "boîte à les épices".

Dans les deux cas, il s'agit d'une boîte qui a vocation à contenir des épices, seulement dans le deuxième on a en plus l'idée que cette boîte est le rangement normal pour toutes les épices (de la maison), et pas seulement quelques unes.

Dans ce cas précis, **on parlera donc de boîte à épices si on projette d'y ranger quelques épices et d'en ranger d'autres ailleurs** (par exemple dans d'autres boîtes à épices ou dans un récipient à épices), et de **boîte aux épices si il s'agit d'une boîte qui abritera toutes les épices de la maison** (par exemple si on est un Navigateur qui n'a pas besoin de curry, de cumin ou de coriandre, seulement d'une seule sorte d'Epice, on peut avoir sa boîte aux épices au bureau).

La distinction peut aussi se faire pour les autres sortes de boîtes: une boîte aux chaussures serait une boîte dans laquelle on range toutes les chaussures. On comprend que cet objet soit assez peu utilisé de part son aspect peu pratique.