# La « boîte à lettres » ou la « boîte aux lettres » ?

Tags: expressions, articles, régionalismes, syntaxe

[*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/bo%C3%AEte/10034/locution) dit : « Boîte aux ou à lettres, réceptacle où l'on dépose les correspondances qui seront transportées par le service postal ; boîte recevant le courrier d'un particulier ; personne qui assure la transmission de messages clandestins. ». Le [*TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bo%C3%AEte) donne « *boîte aux lettres* ».

---

- Dit-on couramment « boîte à lettres » ou « boîte aux lettres » et y
  a-t-il une différence de sens ?
- Y a-t-il un emploi particulier en France, en Belgique, en Suisse, ou au Québec ?
- Peut-on brièvement expliquer ce qui peut jouer sur la présence ou l'absence
  de l'article dans ce genre de [contexte](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/19562) ?

Answer (score 8):

Personellement, ayant vécu en France et en Belgique, je dirais que 'boîte aux lettres' est bien plus commun que 'boîte à lettres'.

En effet, les sites suivants ont l'air de favoriser cet usage aussi:

(Gouvernement français) https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/reuses/trouve-une-boite/

(Poste canadienne) https://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/personal/productsservices/send/letterboxes.jsf?LOCALE=fr

(Poste belge) http://www.bpost.be/site/fr/residential/letters-cards/receive/guidelines_mailbox.html

(Page Wikipédia) https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bo%C3%AEte_aux_lettres

Comment: Pas forcément, ma séléction est basée sur le fait qu'il y a très peu de sites dédiés aux boîtes aux lettres pour particuliers. Il me semble que cette recherche Amazon indique aussi que la majorité des boîtes pour particuliers sont désignées comme boîtes aux lettres: https://www.amazon.fr/s/ref=sr_pg_1?rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Aboites+lettres&keywords=boites+lettres

Comment: ref. : _Cela signifie-t-il qu'on emploie autant boîte aux lettres pour la boîte du particulier, par opposition aux boîtes publiques ?_ Je vous invite à préciser en réponse et à y ajouter ces informations. Peut-être qu'on parle moins de sa boîte que de celle dans la rue et que la nuance passe inaperçue ? Merci !

Comment: Pour avoir toujours vécu en France, je n'ai quasiment jamais entendu "boîte à lettres", que ce soit pour une boîte publique ou particulière.

Comment: Idem pour moi en Belgique

Comment: De même [pour la poste suisse](https://www.post.ch/fr/particuliers/index-thematique-pour-les-particuliers/depot-d-envois/depot-de-lettres-pour-les-particuliers/boite-aux-lettres-publique)

Comment: @SwissFr La poste suisse dit quoi pour la boîte des particuliers par opposition à la boîte publique, le cas échéant ? C'est que le cadre de la question est plus vaste que celui de lister tous les services postaux du monde francophone pour déterminer s'ils disent boîte aux lettres pour la boîte qu'ils administrent. N'hésitez pas à faire une réponse particulière pour la Suisse. Merci !

Answer (score 6):

Au *LBU14* (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, §586 d 2°) on explique que la *boîte aux lettres* a d'abord désigné la boîte qui reçoit le courrier destiné à l'acheminement, puis la boîte des destinataires. On dit que *boîte à lettres* est peu signalé mais qu'elle s'est *vigoureusement* répandue en France - *et non en Belgique* indique-t-on - surtout dans le sens de la boîte des particuliers. On note que le TLFi n'en traite qu'à son article sur [*à*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0) comme d'un néologisme avec la préposition sans article qui introduit un complément de destination ici : « Rare. À + subst. actualisé : l'assiette au beurre (pop.) la boîte aux lettres (néol. : boîte à lettres) la cruche au cidre (pop.) ».

---

Au *DHLF* (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, ed. A. Rey, chez Robert) on observe l'« emploi critiqué et en recul », sans doute familier, de *boîte à [malle](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8364325)* au Québec, par calque de l'anglais *mail box*. Pour la *boîte à/aux lettres*, personnellement je reconnais les deux mais ne saurais dire lequel est plus usuel pour moi. Je ne sais pas non plus ce qu'implique exactement l'affirmation au *LBU* en ce qui a trait à la Belgique ou à la Suisse. Par ailleurs voir aussi [terminologie](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=bo%C3%AEte%20aux%20lettres&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) en informatique.

---

Généralement l'article défini sert à préciser le nom, et quand un nom a la fonction syntaxique de compléter un autre nom, et qu'il désigne la « destination d'un récipient », l'article est d'*ordinaire* omis (la *boîte à bijoux*) ; et maintenu, au figuré (le *pot aux roses*). On parle d'*hésitations* dans l'usage avec un cas comme la *boîte à/aux lettres*. (LBU14)

Comment: D'autres réponses sont les bienvenues. Merci.

Comment: D'après les volumes de recherche en ligne, *boîte à lettres* est un usage minoritaire par rapport à "boîte aux lettres", qui semble relativement stable autour de 15% des requêtes. S'il y a eu engouement "vigoureux" pour la tournure, cela indique qu'il se serait stabilisé depuis 2004. Malheureusement il y a trop peu de volume pour voir les différences régionales. https://www.google.fr/trends/explore#q=%22bo%C3%AEte%20%C3%A0%20lettres%22%2C%20%22bo%C3%AEte%20aux%20lettres%22&cmpt=q&tz=Etc%2FGMT%2B7

Comment: Oui c'est une bonne idée. Je me suis gardé de mettre l'info sur les tendances de recherche en réponse car c'est très parcellaire mais l'ai mise en commentaire pour partager une coordonnée supplémentaire du problème...

Answer (score 3):

Je suis d'accord avec ceci : "Généralement l'article défini sert à préciser le nom, et quand un nom a la fonction syntaxique de compléter un autre nom, et qu'il désigne la « destination d'un récipient », l'article est d'ordinaire omis (la boîte à bijoux)"

La boîte AUX (=à les) lettres implique que l'on devrait préciser de quelles lettres il s'agit. Par exemple : la boîte aux lettres de l'entreprise, la boîte aux lettres vertes, la boîte aux lettres venant de l'étranger...etc.
La boîte À lettres convient pour toutes les lettres, quelles qu'elles soient !

Personnellement, j'ai toujours utilisé cette dernière forme qui est la plus logique grammaticalement parlant.

Answer (score -3):

On ne dit pas boîte aux chaussures. J'opte de prendre l'habitude de dire boîte à lettres.

Comment: Il n'y a qu'une seule paire de chaussure dans une boîte à chaussures, alors qu'il y a souvent plusieurs lettres et/ou magazines et/ou colis dans une boîte aux lettres.